# ARMv8-A (Cortex A53) : Multiply float16 complex by float32 complex

Tags: arm

In RAM I have the following data:
[X0, Y0], [X1, Y1], [X2, Y2], ...
Each number is **float 16**. Each pair is a complex number:
For example:
X0 +i(Y0)

Second buffer has the following data:
[A0, B0], [A1, B1], [A2, B2], ...
Each number is **float 32**. Each pair is a complex number:
For example:
A0 +i(B0)

I have to calculate the scalar multiply of the complex numbers.
The first result is:
[X0 * A0 - Y0 * B0, X0 * B0 + Y0 * A0], [X1 * A1 - Y1 * B1, X1 * B1 + Y1 * A1], ...

Should I do it in the following way (partial code only ) ?

```
float16x4x2_t VecA= vld1_f16_x2  //load 4 x 2 x float 16
float32x4 Re = vcvt_f32_f16 (VecIn[0]) //convert float 16x4 to float 32x4
float32x4 VecB = vld2q_f32 // load 4x2xfloat32 
float32x4 Im = VecB[0];
vmulq_f32 (Re, Im)
...
```

Thank you,
Zvika

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what you want to do?  Pseudocode would help.  Also, please clarify if you are in 32-bit or 64-bit mode.

Comment: Hi Nate. Thank you for your comment. I modified the question. Hope it's clear now. What do you mean by 64-bit mode ? I'm running under Ubuntu - 64bits

Comment: Thanks, this is more clear.  I was talking about the fact that ARMv8-A includes both AArch32 and AArch64 instruction sets which are quite different.  But it sounds like you are using AArch64.

Comment: Do you want the results as pairs of float16 or float32?

Comment: A good start might be to write it in C with appropriate use of `restrict`, let a compiler vectorize it, and see what the code looks like.  There might still be a fair amount of hand optimization possible, and then you can convert it back to intrinsics.